# iOS10 swift 3 streaming audio

Tags: audio, swift3, stream, avfoundation, ios10

I going play stream audio in my app, but I have problem with this task.

```
func playSound(file : String) {
    let path = "http://example/files/audio/\(file).mp3"
    let url = URL(string: path)
    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
    if player?.rate == 0
    {
        player!.play()
    } else {
        player!.pause()
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Error:

```
playing nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

What I doing wrong? How I can use stream audio in my project?

Comment: you need to check your optionals, e.g. was that url actually non nil?

Comment: How I can check it? My syntax is wrong (let url = URL(string: path))? Do you have working code example?

Comment: Set a breakpoint after the "let url = ..." line. Look at the variables inspector (in the debug pane at the bottom of the Xcode window, and if you don't know what that is, stop here and study basic Xcode debugging). Look to see if url is nil. Considering that your logs literally say "playing nil", I assume that's the problem.